# In Texas is it okay for a person to post photos on a commercial website of private property without the owner's permission?

Tags: property, website

We hired someone to build decks on our property.  He did not do a good job, finish the job, etc.  He took photos and posted them on his company website.  Is there anything I can do to have them removed?

Comment: It would make a difference if the contractor is claiming that photos of work done by other people are actually of his work; but pictures of his work on his website do not need your consent.

Answer (score -1):

The owner of the premises can prohibit what they like on their property, including photography *from* their property. They have no control of  photography *of* their property from someone else's property.

In the circumstances, the contractor was there with your permission and, unless you said otherwise, such permission would reasonably include the right to take photographs. He took photos (and they are his photos, not yours) so he can do what he likes with them.